# Underline a certain word in my navigation when on top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a little glitch where when you scroll to the very top of my page the class **active** (which detects the active section of my page and underlines the fitting link in my navbar) gets removed from `#home`. I tried to fix that using something like this:

```js
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if (st.scrollTop == 0) {
    $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
}
```

This didn't quite work.

This is the rest of my javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
    var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
    var windowH = $(window).height();

    $('.section').height(windowH);

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (st.scrollTop == 0) {
            $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        }

        // for the nav bar:
        // if (st > navTop) {
        //     $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
        //     $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        //         'margin-top': navHeight
        //     }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
        // } else {
        //     $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
        //     $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        //         'margin-top': '0'
        //     });
        // }

        $('.section').each(function (index, element) {
            if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
                $(this).addClass('active');

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
                // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
                //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I unfortunately lost the source from where I got the code(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked if my page was at the top with

```
 if(window.scrollY==0)
```

and when it was I added the class `active`

```
{
    element.classList.add("active");
    }
```

and this somehow worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I use same concept like your code. But, I make it separately to make easier to understand. Firstly, take offset and height of every section. Secondly, calculate if the scrolling page between the element. Lastly, if the scrolling page between element set active on the target. You can call the element which have id, just by type the id; I got this when I want to make sure if the script success to load, so I set the id same as the object, when I use the id it became the element.

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  if (!window.$) location.reload(); //Sometimes jQuery failed to load, so I reload the page
  
  //Take pos (offset) and height elelement
  var pH = [];
  $("section").each(function(){
    pH.push([this.offsetTop, $(this).height()]);
  });
  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
    var pos = this.scrollY + $(sc).height(), //Position when scrolling
    index = pH.findIndex(x => pos >= x[0] && pos <= x[0]+x[1]); //index element of position scrolling between the element
    if (index >= 0) {
      //Make sure only 1 class "active"
      //Remove all class "active" then add class "active" on above element
      $("span", sc) //sc is an id's element
      .removeClass("active")
      .eq(index).addClass("active");
     }
     else {
       //Remove class "active" If the scrolling position outside the element
       $("span.active", sc).removeClass("active");
     }
  })
})
```

CSS

```
#sc > .active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-top bg-primary" id="sc" style="color: lightblue;">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<section>1</section>
<section>2</section>
<section>3</section>
<p style="padding: 60vh 0;">Hi</p>
```